# Reading from input file in command line

Tags: java, input

This time I have a very lame problem, which was working perfectly but now its not:

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));

        while (br.readLine() != null) {
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
        }
```

Input file:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

In command line: $java myprogram < inputfile

The result of the above written code is:

```
    2
    4
    6
    8
null
```

But the expected output should be same as input file!

Where am I going wrong?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling br.readLine() twice.  It's calling it once in the while condition and once to actually print it out.  That's why you are only printing every other line.

Edit: Your condition should be:

```
while(br.ready()){
     System.out.println(br.readLine());
}
```

Comment: Depending on the underlying streams and readers, this could exit prematurely. The `ready()` method only tests whether the reader is guaranteed not to block, not whether there is more input.

Comment: Now that was a pure java newbie question! :P

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't call `readLine()` twice in each loop.

Each time you call it, it reads a new line. Print the result of each call:

```
while (true) {
  String line = br.readLine();
  if (line == null)
    break;
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your code like:

```
String str=null;
   while ((str=br.readLine())!= null) {
      System.out.println(str);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

[code from this blog](http://www.cipherbase.co.in/2014/06/java-program-to-read-input-from-file.html)

```
FileReader f = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(f);
String line;
// Read file line by line and print on the console
while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)   {
        System.out.println(line);
}
```